# Why are my lines getting thicker and thicker?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I try to draw some lines with different colors.

This code tries to draw two rectangles with 1px thin lines. However, the second rectangle is drawn with 2px width lines, while the first one is drawn with 1px width.

```
- (void)addLineFrom:(CGPoint)p1 to:(CGPoint)p2 context:(CGContextRef)context {  
    // set the current point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, p1.x, p1.y);

    // add a line from the current point to the wanted point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, p2.x, p2.y);
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPoint from, to;



    // ----- draw outer black frame (left, bottom, right) -----
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    // set the color
    CGFloat lineColor[4] = {26.0f * colorFactor, 26.0f * colorFactor, 26.0f * colorFactor, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, lineColor);

    // left
    from = CGPointZero;
    to = CGPointMake(0.0f, rect.size.height);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    // bottom
    from = to;
    to = CGPointMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    // right
    from = to;
    to = CGPointMake(rect.size.width, 0.0f);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextClosePath(context);



    // ----- draw the middle light gray frame (left, bottom, right) -----

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    // set the color
    CGFloat lineColor2[4] = {94.0f * colorFactor, 94.0f * colorFactor, 95.0f * colorFactor, 1.0f};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, lineColor2);

    // left
    from = CGPointMake(200.0f, 1.0f);
    to = CGPointMake(200.0f, rect.size.height - 2.0f);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    // bottom
    from = to;
    to = CGPointMake(rect.size.width - 2.0f, rect.size.height - 2.0f);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    // right
    from = to;
    to = CGPointMake(rect.size.width - 2.0f, 1.0f);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    // top
    from = to;
    to = CGPointMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    [self addLineFrom:from to:to context:context];

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Comment: Line-thickening:  It affects us all!  :-)

Comment: shoud I guess something? Or are you saying that those line thickness problems are very common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory serves, antialiasing is on by default which may cause more pixels to be affected by your drawing than you intend. Turn antialiasing off for your `CGContextRef` and see if that helps.

iOS:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[context setShouldAntialias:NO];
```

Mac:

```
CGContextRef context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
[context setShouldAntialias:NO];
```

Comment: how to turn off the antialiasing of CGContextRef??

Comment: `CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false);` disables antialiasing of a `CGContextRef`.

Answer (score 1):

The first one *appears* to be one pixel thick because you've drawn it around the perimeter of the dirty rect, which UIView clipped to for you, making it an inner stroke. But, in fact, **both rectangles have the same problem**.

On another question, I wrote [a full description of the real problem and the real solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488115/how-to-set-up-a-user-quartz2d-coordinate-system-with-scaling-that-avoids-fuzzy-dr/2488796#2488796). Turning off AA will suffice for straight lines, but you'll hate it as soon as you draw rotated or draw a diagonal.