# Is Cocoa animator proxy unable to handle 0.5 points?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview

I'm trying to move the origin of a custom view.
If I directly set the new origin for the frame, everything is working fine as expected.

```
[MyView setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0.5, 0.5)];
```

If I try to animate the movement with the proxy animator.

```
[[MyView animator] setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0.5, 0.5)];
```

The new origin will be (1, 1) instead of (0.5, 0.5).
Am I doing something wrong?
Is `animator` unable to handle 0.5 points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the animator proxy is helpfully correcting a frame that would result in blurry edges and/or text. Drawing things across pixel borders (0.5, 0.5 vs. 1.0, 1.0 or 0.0, 0.0) is rarely useful unless you're *trying* to make something blurry (like a shadow, or glow).

You may very well have a good reason for doing this, but it's probably best to ask "why?"

Comment: Yes. Actually what I'm trying to do is this:
* an NSView which draws a rounded rect
* the rounded rect is drawn starting from an NSRect that is derived from NSInsetRect([self bounds], 0.5, 0.5)
* draw a stroke to the NSBezierPath with line width 1.0
* add the custom view that I want to animate inside the NSBezierPath

From my tests 0.5 for inset and 1.0 for line width give me the best visual result.
But probably I'm making everything to complicated.

Comment: massimoperi: You might prefer to use an inner stroke, as I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488115/how-to-set-up-a-user-quartz2d-coordinate-system-with-scaling-that-avoids-fuzzy-drawing