# Core Graphics stroke width is inconsistent between lines & arcs?

Tags: macos, ios, core-graphics

The use case: I am subclassing UIView to create a custom view that "mattes" a UIImage with a rounded rectangle (clips the image to a rounded rect).  The code is working; I've used a method similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349400/how-can-i-remove-a-uiview-with-rounded-corners-from-its-parent-view).

However, I want to stroke the clipping path to create a "frame".  This works, but the arc strokes look markedly different than the line strokes.  I've tried adjusting the stroke widths to greater values (I thought it was pixelation at first), but the anti-aliasing seems to handle arcs and lines differently.

Here's what I see on the simulator:

[image: Uneven stroke image]

This is the code that draws it:

```
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 0, STROKE_OPACITY);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
CGContextAddPath(context, roundRectPath);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Anyone know how to make these line up smoothly?

Comment: Oh, and yes, I need to flip the image here - it's upside-down!  Silly iOS vs. Mac OSX coordinate differences..

Comment: you should use `CGRect b = CGRectInset(self.bounds, strokeWidth/2, strokeWidth/2);` before you round the rect and add it to the context

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> … but the anti-aliasing seems to handle arcs and lines differently.

No, it doesn't.

Your stroke width is consistent—it's 2 pt all the way around.

What's wrong is that you have clipped to a rectangle, and your shape's sides are right on top of the edges of this rectangle, so only the halves of the sides that are inside the rectangle are getting drawn. That's why the edges appear only 1 px wide.

The solution is either not to clip, to grow your clipping rectangle by 2 pt on each axis before clipping to it, or to move your shape's edges inward by 1 pt on each side. (ETA: Or, yeah, do an inner stroke.)

Comment: There's no way to put the stroke on the inside of the path instead of centering it on the path?

Comment: @Gabe: You can do that too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488115/how-to-set-up-a-user-quartz2d-coordinate-system-with-scaling-that-avoids-fuzzy-dr/2488796#2488796

Comment: I found another way to solve my use case (a much simpler one, doh), but this certainly answers the question.  Even when I took out the clipping, I was still experiencing the issue -- but the "center stroke" was the issues: my frame size was equal to the size of my path on the straight edges, so the outside pixel was never being displayed: it is outside of the frame.

Comment: @phooze: The image definitely shows clipping, so if it is clipped even without you clipping, that just means that the framework clips for you and you don't need to clip anyway. (Mac OS X definitely does not do that, so beware of that if you remove the clip and then port this code to Cocoa.)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is trying to do the same thing I am (round rect an image):

The `UIImageView` class has a property `layer`, of type `CALayer` .  CALayer already has this functionality built-in (it WAS a little surprising to me I couldn't find it anywhere):

```
UIImageView *thumbnailView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
thumbnailView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
thumbnailView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
thumbnailView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
[self.view addSubview:thumbnailView];
```

Also does the trick.